# Coldfusion Builder check for updates not working

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusionbuilder

Running CF builder 3, Help > Check for Updates throws an error -- "Unable to read repository at http://ahtik.com/eclipse-update/content.xml.
peer not authenticated". Not sure why it's looking there, but I pasted the url in browser and indeed got a 404 error. Is there a way to change where CFB looks for this update check?

Comment: Can you update it from here? https://www.adobe.com/support/coldfusion/downloads_updates.html#cfb3

Comment: Thanks, I applied the patch at that link, but now I'm getting a different error message when I try to update: "No repository found at file:/Y:/cf_builder/build/../stage/buildRepo/".

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I was getting the "No repository found at file:/Y:/.." message because the path was listed under window > preferences > Install/Update > Available Software Sites.  Y was a network drive that we disabled, but beyond that, it looks like my CFB was incorrectly configured for updates anyway. I spent some time trying to add in the standalone patch at the top of https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/coldfusion-builder-3-updates.html, but kept getting error messages. I inherited this copy of CFB a year ago, so I just did a clean reinstall. After that did Help > Check for Updates, it found and installed an update, restarted CFB, and now everything's good.